# Finding the bottom type in 3D/Multi-Dimentional Array

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, types, associated-types

First of all, thank you for visiting. Currently, I'm trying to find the type of a multi-dimensional array. For example, in the following line,

```
let example = [[5,2,7],[4,8],[9,1,3]]
```

How do you determine the the very bottom type of `example` is `Int`?

I have tried,

```
extension Array {
  func findType() {
    let arrayType = type(of: self).Element.self // Array<Int>
    // let realType = array.Element.self // Error
  }
}
```

It seems like `Element` of `Element` does not exist. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `type(of: Element.self)`

Comment: `Element` is `Array<Int>`.

Comment: `extension Collection where Iterator.Element: Collection {
    func typeOfSub() {
        let arrayType = type(of: Iterator.Element.self.Iterator.Element.self)
        print(arrayType)
    }
}
`

Comment: Just curiosity why do you need that?

Comment: Trying to implement `flatmap` in Swift for multi-dimenstional arrays. In order to return `Array<array<T>>` to `Array<T>` I needed to know what `T` would be.

Comment: Thanks Leo. You've helped me. I have one doubt. Do you think it is possible for you to use recursive to get the very bottom type of, for example. `[[[3]]]` or even more nested arrays?

Comment: I have no idea.